# Why does the chair move by itself?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-village

In [*The Village*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0368447/), when Ivy is standing at the door waiting for Lucius to come back and her sister is asking her to come inside, the camera pans from her sister waiting in the basement trap door to a chair right in front of her and to the right. It moves (from what it seems) all by itself. No one explains why and/or how in the movie or anywhere online. From what I understand no one else has even questioned it!

**Why does the chair move by itself?**

Comment: Do you have a clip of this scene?

Comment: https://youtu.be/GbJpJBKUf4k at 2:56 kitty looks towards the chair and there after was the scene I was referring to but after steve-o's comment I went and watched again. I looked carefully for the chair actually changing position and I admit I couldnt not see that it had actually moved after all though yes its very hard to tell the growl apart from a chair scraping the floor at that part. But now I doubt the chair moved afterall.

Answer (score 4):

**I don't think the chair moved at all.**

As it happens, I own *The Village* on DVD (I'm probably one of about ten people who liked it enough to buy it. =P)  Anyway, I watched the scene in question (which occurs roughly around the 31-32 minute mark for those interested in double-checking) and I didn't see the chair you refer to move.

The camera pans over to our left (Kitty's right) and there's a chair there, which takes up most of the frame for about a second.  Then the camera appears to move slightly forward and back before returning to Kitty in the trap door.  I'm guessing this is what gave you the impression that the chair moved, but it was actually the camera.  At the same time that the camera is doing this, there's a low growling noise, which I think is supposed to be the monster outside the house, but you may have misinterpreted to be the noise of the chair dragging on the floor.